# Constrain UICollectionView height to match height of contents

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch

I have a UICollectionView using UICollectionViewFlowLayout. The scroll direction is vertical but I only have a small (variable) number of cells and do not need or want scrolling. The collection view top, leading, and trailing are constrained to the parent view. I'm trying to get the collection view height to fit its contents.

The initial height looks correct if I use this:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate {
    var collection: UICollectionView!
    var heightConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!

    override func loadView() {
        super.loadView()
        self.collection = UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout())
        self.collection.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        self.view.addSubview(self.collection)
        // ...
        self.collection.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor).isActive = true
        self.collection.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        self.collection.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor).isActive = true

        // Create placeholder constraint
        self.heightConstraint = self.collection.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 1)
        self.heightConstraint.isActive = true
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, willDisplay cell: UICollectionViewCell, forItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        // Update placeholder constraint
        self.heightConstraint.constant = self.collection.contentSize.height
    }

    // ...
}
```

But that doesn't update the collection view's height when the content layout changes, such as on device orientation changes. Is there a way to update the constraint constant when the content layout changes? Or a way to use a dynamic constraint instead of a constant?

Swift 4.2, Xcode 10.0, target iOS 12.

Comment: Off-topic: you should not override `loadView` like this, you should override `viewDidLoad` for that. `loadView` is intended to create a custom view.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A better location to update the constraint is `viewDidLayoutSubviews`, which gets called after every re-layout (orientation changes, size changes, etc). Also, it's more reliable to ask the collection view layout for the content size:

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()

    // Update placeholder constraint
    self.heightConstraint.constant = self.collection.collectionViewLayout.collectionViewContentSize.height
}
```

Comment: In my case `self.collection.collectionViewLayout.collectionViewContentSize.height` always zero :(

Comment: Fixed it with `invalidateLayout` after `reloadData`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution:

```
lazy var collectionView: UICollectionView = {
    let collection = UICollectionView(frame:CGRect.zero, collectionViewLayout: collectionViewFlowLayout)
    collection.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    collection.backgroundColor = .red
    collection.register(UICollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "myCollectionCell")
    return collection
}()

var defaultConstraints: [NSLayoutConstraint]?

var heightConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint]?

let collectionViewFlowLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout = {
    let flow = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    flow.scrollDirection = .vertical
    flow.itemSize = CGSize(width: 120.0, height: 170.0)
    return flow
}()

override func updateViewConstraints() {
super.updateViewConstraints()
    if defaultConstraints == nil {
        defaultConstraints = [
            collectionView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor),
            collectionView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor),
            collectionView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor),
            collectionView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.collectionView.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor)
        ]
         heightConstraint = [collectionView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100)]
heightConstraint?.first!.priority = .defaultHigh
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate(defaultConstraints! + heightConstraint!)
    }

}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    view.addSubview(self.collectionView)
    collectionView.delegate = self
    collectionView.dataSource = self
    view.updateConstraintsIfNeeded()
}

override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
     heightConstraint?.first?.constant = collectionView.collectionViewLayout.collectionViewContentSize.height
}


func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 3
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "myCollectionCell", for: indexPath)
    cell.backgroundColor = .yellow
    return cell
}

func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
    return 1
}
```